# Can I use environment variables in the "config.in" of buildroot?

Tags: buildroot

I wonder if I can access environment variables (or argument passed when running make) in buildroot `.in` files. For example, I like to have a `Config.in` file like this:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_MY_PACKAGE
        bool "my_package"
        select BR2_PACKAGE_XYZ if $(NEED_XYZ) = "y"
        select BR2_PACKAGE_GTEST
        help
          This is my package.
```

where `NEED_XYZ` is an environment variable (or make variable). Can I have such configuration file? If no, what do you suggest to achieve similar behavior?